# Convert BufferedInputStream to String in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure, bufferedinputstream

mock.request is returning the response :body as a BufferedInputStream. I need to print and compare this as a string. How do I convert it?

When I try to pass response as a message to my assertion, I see a raw output, e.g.

```
(is (= 200 (:status response) (:body response)))
=> #object[java.io.BufferedInputStream 0x211bdf40 java.io.BufferedInputStream@211bdf40]
```

Related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string) are Java-specific.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just [`slurp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp) it:

```
(slurp (:body response))
```

Comment: Thanks. I also had to ensure my API calls returned `(resp/response "some body")` otherwise the response would not be a stream. I.e. Just returning "ok" was just a string and slurp would try to open it as a file.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use https://github.com/ztellman/byte-streams:

```
(convert (:body res) String)
```